# Scenekit - level of detail for materials/textures

Tags: swift, xcode, 3d, scenekit

Is it possible to have different materials resolutions for different level of details (SCNLevelOfDetail)?

I know SCNLevelOfDetail is supposed to be used with different Geometries resolution, but what about materials/textures?

Example:

- For a extremely close up, I would have a very high resolution texture.
- For a far away view, I would have a lower resolution texture.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Materials are attached to geometries. You can `copy` the `SCNGeometry` and then change its materials. The copy is cheap (because the underlying vertex data is shared) and you can create a `SCNLevelOfDetail` with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! : )  Got it, makes sense! Would it also be possible to use same approach with the new tesselation/subvision features? Example, you provide a high resolution texture that SceneKit uses on the high resolution mesh. And on the coarse mesh it uses a lower resolution texture ). Would be amazing if the  resolution compression was generated on the fly! But if not possible, manually assigning different textures resolutions according to auto tesselationn would alteado be great.